# Laravel migration duplicate class name in database/ and vendors/

Tags: php, laravel, migration

While I'm trying to install a Laravel application, I encounter a different result on my localhost, and on the server:

By doing:

```
git clone -b my_branch http://my_repo.git test && cp ./saved/.env ./test && cd ./test && composer install && php artisan migrate
```

`php artisan migrate` is returning the error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Cannot declare class CreateTelescopeEntriesTable, because the name is already in use

but only on the distant server (Ubuntu), and not on my localhost (Debian)

The two files in conflict are:

- database/migrations/2018_11_20_120000_create_telescope_entries_table.php
- vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/migrations/2018_08_08_100000_create_telescope_entries_table.php

(It's confirmed, if I remove one of them the migration is running)

So, I'm wondering why the artisan migrate is loading the vendor migration, only on the server.

- Composer version are identical (and the composer dump-autoload doesn't help)
- php at version 7.2.10 on server against 7.2.12 on localhost
- I see nothing strange in .env, which are really close on both environments
- Laravel : ^5.7

**Did you encounter something like this, what should I check?**

For me the correct behavior is the one on my localhost.
Thanks

**Edit**: Okay, that was stupid, my migration table was different, with migrate:fresh I got the same problem on the two sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migration table was different, with migrate:fresh you will got the same problem on the two sides.